# Creating a Simple Random Number in .NET

Tags: c#, random

I need a simple random number for a loop that I am creating, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong here.  Can someone look at the code below and explain to me why it's giving me the following errors:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Random.Next(int,
> int)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert
> from 'decimal' to 'int'
> Error  3   Argument 2: cannot convert from
> 'decimal' to 'int'

I am trying to pull minimum and maximum values for the range from Numeric Up/Down controls.  I would assume that LINQ or C# would have a simple, one line generator, but  I can't find it.

```
Random rnd1 = new Random();
var integer = rnd1.Next(numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value, 
                                                  numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value);
textbox.Text = integer.ToString();
```

Comment: What syntax errors?

Comment: Are you sure that `numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value` and `numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value` are both of type `int` or `Int32` ?

Comment: I don't see any problem here if your `numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value `and `numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value` are not `int32`.

Comment: or if they even have values yet? You're not trying this in a constructor are you?

Comment: I'm learning here, so the whole voting down is ridiculous.

Comment: Anyway, I think you have the answer now.

Comment: @Jeagr The voting is based on the quality of the question, which is completely independent of the quality of the code.  The main problem that stands out with the question is that you didn't include enough of the code to actually reproduce the problem.  Without knowing what `numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value` and `numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value`, we can't really do much, and that's clearly where the root of your problem lies.  A novice programmer can ask a high quality question, and a very advanced programmer can ask a very poor quality question; the voting is mostly based on the question quality.

Comment: I have voted you up for improving the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumericUpDown.Value returns a decimal, while Next() accepts an integer. You probably want to cast it to an integer first:

```
var integer = rnd1.Next((int)numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value, (int)numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all `numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value` and `..._RandomMax.Value` are not `int`, so you might need to cast:

```
var integer = rnd1.Next((int)numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value, (int)numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value);
```

Other than that, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 2):

NumericUpDown is a decimal, you need to convert to an int.

```
var integer = rnd1.Next((int)numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value, (int)numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Random.Next` expects two `Int32` values, but `NumericUpDown.Value` property is a `decimal`. Because conversion from `decimal` to `int` looses some value precision you have to do it explicitly :

```
rnd1.Next((int)numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value, (int)numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [`NumericUpDown.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value.aspx)'s return type is `Decimal`, you need to *explicitly* convert your `numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value` and `numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value` values to `Int32` because [`Random.Next(Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) takes two parameter as `Int32`. Like;

```
Random rnd1 = new Random();
var integer = rnd1.Next((int)numericUpDown_RandomMin.Value, (int)numericUpDown_RandomMax.Value);
textbox.Text = integer.ToString();
```